# App crashes when try to reconnect using Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, bluetooth-lowenergy, reactive

I am working on an IOT project based on BLE. I used BLE along with reactive java 2.
When I try to reconnect with the sensor device, app crashes throws two types of error.
1) io.reactivex.undeliverableException
2) onErroNotImplementedException

But the same code works fine many times. The above mentioned crashes appear very randomly.
I am able to connect with the sensor device many times, but after 4 to 5 attempts, app just crashes and throws above mentioned error.

Comment: Please consider posting some code snippets of what is mentioned in the stacktraces, also include the stacktraces

Answer (score 0):

The second exception itself explains that the issue is you haven't implemented onError() method for error in connecting to BLE. Just implement that method and the crash will be gone.

Comment: The method is already implemented and works fine but sometime app just crashes with that exception.